# xindy not sorting cross-reference targets

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing, sorting, xindy

When compiling

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{index}
\newindex{i}{idx}{idn}{Index}

\begin{document}
Let's discuss letter d\index[i]{d}\index[i]{letter|see{d}}
and c.\index[i]{c}\index[i]{letter|see{c}}
\newpage
Let's now discuss letter a\index[i]{a}\index[i]{letter|see{a}}
and b.\index[i]{b}\index[i]{letter|see{b}}
\newpage

\printindex[i]

\end{document}
```

with

```
xindy -o xindycrossreforder.idn -L english -M texindy xindycrossreforder.idx
```

I get

> **L**
>
> letter, *see* d; c; a; b

while I need (and would have expected) the cross-reference targets to be sorted by the same rules as the index itself.

Is there an option for `xindy` that I haven't found or could anyone suggest an extension of the sorting rules to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't there some option within the `index` package to achieve this? I am not sure that `xindy` sorts along an index entry

Comment: @ChristianHupfer As far as I can see from `index.sty` `|see` is only formated, but not processed anyhow.